# Where to find External Id for SmsConfiguration in Cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I use [create_user_pool](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.create_user_pool) for creating new Cognito user pools. I see there's a `SmsConfiguration` option which takes an `ExternalId`.
If you set up MFA for your user pool using the Cognito portal, this External Id (which looks like an UUID) will be used in the automatically generated IAM SMS-Role.

Where do I find/generate the value for `ExternalId` if I want to manually (using boto3 or AWS CLI) create the user pool and the IAM SMS role?

My MFA setup looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You're right, it's a UUID that you define in the IAM Role. Here is an example CloudFormation Template with an External ID -

```
CognitoSMSRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement: 
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Principal: 
            Service: 
              - "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
          Action: 
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "sts:ExternalId": 'this-is-my-external-id'
    Path: "/"
CognitoSMSPolicy: 
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
  Properties: 
    PolicyName: "CognitoSMSPolicy"
    PolicyDocument: 
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement: 
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action: 
            - "sns:publish"
          Resource: 
            - "*"
    Roles: 
      - Ref: CognitoSMSRole
```

You can also find the External ID in the console.

IAM -> Roles -> Select your Role -> Trusted Relationships

[image: ExternalID - AWS Console]

Comment: Does this mean I can use an UUID I generated myself for the IAM role?

Comment: Yes you can. If your role is already created, you can add an UUID for external ID. In the console, click "Edit trust relationship" and you'll get a JSON formatted text. The final JSON would look something like - `{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Sid": "", "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "Service": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com" }, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", "Condition": { "StringEquals": { "sts:ExternalId": "this-is-my-external-id" } } } ] }`

Comment: If you're trying to add the External ID to an already existing role via aws cli. You need to use the `update-assume-role-policy` [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/update-assume-role-policy.html)